# How to center an arrow in a table cell?

Tags: css

I would like to center the arrow on each cell, but I can't do it.

```
.positive-arrow:before {
     content: "";
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px 5px;
     border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
}
```

I tried with `position: absolute; left: 65%;`, but it's diy....

```
.positive-arrow:before {
     content: "";
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px 5px;
     border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
     position: absolute; 
     left: 65%;
}
```

Do you know a better solution in CSS, please?

Thank you

```css
.w5 {
  width: 5%;
}


.w30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.positive-arrow:before {
     content: "";
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px 5px;
     border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
}
 .negative-arrow:before {
     content: "";
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px 5px;
     border-color: #f00 transparent transparent transparent; 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <body>
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th scope="col" class="w30">Indice</th>
                     <th scope="col" class="w30">Place</th>
                     <th scope="col" class="w5 text-center">Cours</th>
                     <th colspan="2" class="w5 text-center">Variation</th>
                     <th scope="col" class="w30 text-center">Date et heure</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>DAX Composite</td>
                     <td >EuroNext</td>
                     <td class="text-end">1 265,45</td>
                     <td class="text-end"> <span class="positive-arrow"></span></td>
                     <td class="text-end">1,50 %</td>
                     <td class="text-center">21/11/2022 - 17:55</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>DAX</td>
                     <td>EuroNext</td>
                     <td class="text-end">14 379,93</td>
                         <td class="text-end"> <span class="negative-arrow"></span></td>
                     <td class="text-end">3,40 %</td>
                     <td class="text-center">21/11/2022 - 17:55</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Mid Cap DAX</td>
                     <td>EuroNext</td>
                     <td class="text-end">5 379,93</td>
                            <td class="text-end"> <span class="positive-arrow"></span></td>
                     <td class="text-end">1,40 %</td>
                     <td class="text-center">21/11/2022 - 17:55</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Building an arrow using this method (borders with transparency) effectively creates a rectangle made of four triangles, the top/bottom triangle is made visible by giving it a colour and that's how you get the "arrow". So using this method, it's not easy to exactly centre it using normal methods as the arrow relies on additional invisible arrows taking up space to display correctly, resulting in an offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your pseudo elements inline block and then if you want to horizontally center them, change the class on the td to `text-center` (instead of `text-end`).  If you want to vertically center them, then you need to add vertical align middle to the `td`

```css
.w5 {
  width: 5%;
}

.w30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.positive-arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
}

.negative-arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px;
  border-color: #f00 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.vertical-center {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="w30">Indice</th>
      <th scope="col" class="w30">Place</th>
      <th scope="col" class="w5 text-center">Cours</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="w5 text-center">Variation</th>
      <th scope="col" class="w30 text-center">Date et heure</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>DAX Composite</td>
      <td>EuroNext</td>
      <td class="text-end">1 265,45</td>
      <td class="text-center vertical-center"> <span class="positive-arrow"></span></td>
      <td class="text-end">1,50 %</td>
      <td class="text-center">21/11/2022 - 17:55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DAX</td>
      <td>EuroNext</td>
      <td class="text-end">14 379,93</td>
      <td class="text-center vertical-center"> <span class="negative-arrow"></span></td>
      <td class="text-end">3,40 %</td>
      <td class="text-center">21/11/2022 - 17:55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mid Cap DAX</td>
      <td>EuroNext</td>
      <td class="text-end">5 379,93</td>
      <td class="text-center vertical-center"> <span class="positive-arrow"></span></td>
      <td class="text-end">1,40 %</td>
      <td class="text-center">21/11/2022 - 17:55</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```